# Google Maps SDK Tutorial Crash

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to get Google Maps set up in my iOS application, but am getting a crash on an InvalidArgumentException.

A few people have asked this same question already; however, they have either not gotten helpful responses, or the responses that were given did not solve the problem.

The code is copied directly from Google's [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start) page:

```
#import "XXMapViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface XXMapViewController ()

@end

@implementation XXMapViewController{
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                            longitude:151.20
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;

    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
    marker.title = @"Sydney";
    marker.snippet = @"Australia";
    marker.map = mapView_;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

@end
```

This is the line it crashes on, so I have determined it's not a problem with setting the view:

`mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];`

And here is the stack trace (app name is X'd out for anonymity's sake):

```
2014-04-17 14:24:19.909 XX App[28758:60b] -[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ae45a80
2014-04-17 14:24:19.931 XX App[28758:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ae45a80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b2b495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010388a99e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103bbc65d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b1cd8d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103b1c938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   XX        App                       0x0000000100189323 -[GMSMapView setCamera:] + 161
    6   XX        App                       0x0000000100187cc2 -[GMSMapView sharedInitWithServices:camera:] + 1440
    7   XX        App                       0x00000001001870be -[GMSMapView initWithFrame:camera:] + 121
    8   XX        App                       0x0000000100186f5f +[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:] + 102
    9   XX        App                       0x000000010000eeae -[XXMapViewController viewDidLoad] + 238
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010252d59e -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 562
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010252d777 -[UIViewController view] + 29
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001025442c5 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 628
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010254f6f5 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 401
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000102550238 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010266a895 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000102497993 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100e77802 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100e6c369 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100e6c1ea _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100ddffb8 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 252
    21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100de1030 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 394
    22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000100de169d _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103af6dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103af6d37 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ad6522 __CFRunLoopRun + 946
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000103ad5d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010491cf04 GSEventRunModal + 161
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000102437e33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    29  XX        App                       0x000000010000ed93 main + 115
    30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010434c5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have added the -ObjC flag to my project, and have tried adding it to the target as others have recommended; however, adding it to the target causes the build to fail. I created a new single view project as well, which worked fine when following the exact same instructions.I have the correct API key and Google Maps for iOS is enabled in my API console. This has been extraordinarily frustrating and a huge wall in the way of finishing my project. If anybody could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What error do you get when you put -ObjC on the target?

Comment: I get a bunch of Mach-O errors that look like they are related to Parse, which I am using for my back end. All of them seem to have to do with Facebook token authentication, which is bizarre because I have nothing in my code that uses Facebook.


`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)`


And the other 8 errors look more or less like that.

Comment: Amazing how one simple question can point me in the right direction. It was a conflict with Parse dependencies. The solution was to either eliminate the FB SDK dependencies or to just download the SDK. I chose the latter since I will inevitably be using it with my app. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries Tatonka, I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a conflict with Parse dependencies. The solution was to either eliminate the FB SDK dependencies or to just download the SDK. I chose the latter since I will inevitably be using it with my app.